# calling c function from C#

Tags: c#, .net, function

as a simple example, i have a C function which receives an int,increment it and return incremented value.on the other side I enter the input number to textbox in C#.
how can i call C function to process the number and return it back from c#?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke).

You do will need a Reference to `System.Runtime.InteropServices` and then do the following, if your C DLL contains a function called `increase_int`:

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll")]
private static extern int increase_int(int in_value);
```

and use it from your code doing

```
int newValue = increase_int(oldValue);
```

Comment: hi,I cant debug the program,why the control not going into called function when step over(F11)...?

Comment: You can't debug a C dll using the standard debug mechanisms of .Net.

Comment: That link to the MSDN-magazine does point to the index of all issues, not to an issue or article. Can someone provide a working link or at least issue number?

Comment: @NobbZ I cannot find the article any more, as Microsoft does not believe in Tim Berners-Lee's dogma "cool URLs don't change". I will replace it with another tutorial that is hopefully available from that URL for longer.